# How to read an Excel file in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-batch

Could someone explain how to load Excel data into Apache Flink?. I have seen in the API Doc other kind of formats such as txt, csv but not Excel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@AntonioN.G. I was able to find this for you:

https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice/wiki/Using-Flink-DataSource-DataSink-API-to-read-write-Excel-files-(Simple-format)

This should give you a good starting point.